# can I force server to always use turboboost?

Tags: turbo-boost

I'm using HP DL360p Gen8 with 2 * Xeon E5-2640.
I do not load CPU 100%, i load it only ~10% and so I guess turboboost is not activated.
However I'm using my server for trading so I absolutely don't care about CPU loading but I always want to process my data asap. So I want server to operate using maximum 3 GHz.

I.e. 90% of CPU time I don't have anything to process. 10% of CPU time I have data to process. But I need to process it ASAP. I need every single microsecond. So I want server to operate always at maximum "turboboosted" mode. Is it possible?

Comment: It may be better to overclock the CPU instead, if your system allows this (though it probably does not).

Comment: Do you mean you load it to 100% for 10% of the time, or that it's only loaded to 10% when you process data on it?

Comment: @DarthAndroid no cpu load is constantly about 10%

Comment: @javapowered Then it should already be operating in a fully turboboosted state, presuming that 10% equates to a single core being fully loaded (it most likely does). You still have to look at overclocking to increase it any further.

Comment: no 10% is split between all cores

Comment: @javapowered If 10% is split between all cores, then the CPU is not the bottleneck, and it doesn't matter if it's running turboboosted. The CPU is sitting idle while waiting on other components in your system to feed it data. Overclocking or turboboosting won't get you data any faster, only cause the CPU to draw more power and spend more clockcycles idle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TurboBoost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost) dynamically overclocks the processor based on how many cores are fully loaded. If you are actually loading all the cores on the CPU, you are not seeing 3GHz most likely, even with TurboBoost.

What you would want to actually get a consistent boost is to disable TurboBoost and then overclock the processor up to the speed that you want. Obviously this introduces risk into the system since components are operating over rated capacity, so weigh those against the potential cost of replacing hardware if it is not kept properly cool (google around, see what other people are able to make the processor do, use that to gauge how well it overclocks. If people are consistantly pushing it to 4GHz under full load, then there's a good chance you can hit 3GHz. If a few are struggling to hit 3.2GHz, then be more weary). You might have to replace the cooling fan on the CPU to keep temperatures in check.

Comment: To add to why this is most likely what you want to do... according to Mike Pearce at Intel "For example; the Intel(R) Xeon X7560, is a 2.26GHz chip that supports Turbo Boost to overclock the processor when one or more cores aren't needed. Thus if you are running with less that all the cores of a particular chip, then Turbo Boost may be enabled to boost some cores." which means Turbo Boost doesn't kick ALL the cores up to the OC'd speed.  Only some.  So, if you really need multi-core/multi-processor performance, either take Darth Android's advice, or leave it well enough alone.

Answer (score 0):

Such hardware does not support overclocking, but you can go into the BIOS and set power management to "High performance". If you're running Windows, set the power policy in the OS to "High performance" too. [Under Linux, set the CPU scaling governor to "performance"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021748/set-cpu-governor-to-performance-in-18-04). This won't keep the CPU in turbo boost territory but will keep its minimum at base clock, so there will be less upshifting when the load increases. You may also choose to disable all P-states in the BIOS, this will further reduce CPU response latency, but this will cause a huge increase in idle power draw.